.net Aspire scale to zero
I try to configure my .net Aspire Project that it can scale to zero. I added a scale section to my azure.yaml:
name: Project.AppHost
services:
app:
    language: dotnet
    project: ./Project.AppHost.csproj
    host: containerapp
    scale:
        minReplicas: 0
        maxReplicas: 5

And updated it in the azure portal manually to reflect this. But every time I deploy via azd up it reverts back to minReplicas: 1 and maxReplicas: 10.
Where would I have to set that option so that it survives deployments?
EDIT:
I found the azd infra synth command. Turns out here it overrides my scaling settings:
  template:
    containers:
      - image: {{ .Image }}
        name: apiservice
        env:
          - name: AZURE_CLIENT_ID
            value: {{ .Env.MANAGED_IDENTITY_CLIENT_ID }}
          - name: ASPNETCORE_FORWARDEDHEADERS_ENABLED
            value: "true"
          - name: HTTP_PORTS
            value: '{{ targetPortOrDefault 0 }}'
          - name: OTEL_DOTNET_EXPERIMENTAL_OTLP_EMIT_EVENT_LOG_ATTRIBUTES
            value: "true"
          - name: OTEL_DOTNET_EXPERIMENTAL_OTLP_EMIT_EXCEPTION_LOG_ATTRIBUTES
            value: "true"
          - name: OTEL_DOTNET_EXPERIMENTAL_OTLP_RETRY
            value: in_memory
    scale:
      minReplicas: 1

When I set infra synth on true, I can update it here and the value is set as expected. But with that I a) have to manually update the template every time when I change something on the infrastructure and then go and update the scale settings again since that is overriden then aswell. So I hope someone found a better solution how to do this aspire ^^
EDIT 2:
It seems this is not supported yet:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspire/discussions/4831
